# ASP.Net Redirect rule for all except certain URL

Tags: asp.net, regex

I have the following redirect rules one is for non www url (http://mysite.co.uk/....) and the other is for a www URL to redirect to http://www.mysite2.co.uk/...

Currently the rules are a catch all. I don't want the rules to execute if a certain URL is hit which contains "/mystring/mystring.aspx".

Can anyone help me write the rules for this?

```
    <rule name="Canonical Host Name - mysite" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(?:www|[^.]+\.)*mysite\.co.uk$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.mysite2.co.uk/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>     
    <rule name="Canonical Host - mysite 2" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.mysite\.co.uk$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.mysite2.co.uk/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to accomplish this by adding to the conditions, and using `negate="true"`.  Something like this:

```
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(?:www|[^.]+\.)*mysite\.co.uk$" />
    <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="mystring\/mystring\.aspx" negate="true" />
</conditions>
```